# Send DataGridView to a new page from User Submission

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

I have a web form where a user submits a date range using a jQuery DatePicker.
The DatePicker is then connected to a database and retrieves the information and displays a DataGridView

```
    protected void DataGrid1(string FirstDate, string SecondDate)
    {
        DateTime fFirstDate;
        DateTime sSecondDate;
        DataTable dt = new Datatable(); 
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

        //Check Valid Date Format

        if (DateTime.TryParse(FirstDate, out fFirstDate) && DateTime.TryParse(SecondDate, out sSecondDate))
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
            try
            {
               con.Open();
               string sqlStatement = "SELECT * @DateFrom and @DateTo"
               SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlStatement, con);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom", fFirstDate)
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTo", sSecondDate)
               sqlDataAdapter sql_adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
               sql_adapter.Fill(dt);
               if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
               { 
                  GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                  GridView1.DataBind();
               }
               else
               {}
             catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
             {
                string msg = "Error"
                msg += ex.Message;
                throw new Exception(msg);
             }
             finally
             {
                con.Close();
             }

           //Repeat Try for DataTable2 creating new data source


      }

   }
```

Above I have my code where the database retrieves information from the users submitted date range. Below is the button click code.

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindDataGrid1(TextFirstDate.Text, TextSecondDate.Text);
    }
```

When the user enters the date, the DataGridView is displayed on the same page. Is there a way to to display the datagridview on a new webform after submit?

I tried adding redirect to the button to a new page and establish the html code for the datagridview on a new page, but I can't seem to get it correct since its  a new form.

Comment: after postback you can get at the `dt` if it's declared as public static datatable, you could store the datatable in a Session, and cast it back to a DataTable using the `as` KeyWord.. if you want the DataGridView to be shown on another page.. you will either have to copy and paste that template into the aspx page.. or drop a datagridview on the other form, set the auto generate columns = true .. and bind the datatable to the datagridview as well as assign the GridView.DataSource.. the second form will need a `DataTable variable` declared at the class level  this is actually not that hard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes into your code.By using `DataGrid1(string FirstDate, string SecondDate)`, you need to return `DataTable` as result and store this result into `session` . e.g.

```
protected DataTable DataGrid1(string FirstDate, string SecondDate)
   {
        DateTime fFirstDate;
        DateTime sSecondDate;
        DataTable dt = new Datatable(); 
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

        //Check Valid Date Format

        if (DateTime.TryParse(FirstDate, out fFirstDate) && DateTime.TryParse(SecondDate, out sSecondDate))
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
            try
            {
               con.Open();
               string sqlStatement = "SELECT * @DateFrom and @DateTo"
               SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlStatement, con);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateFrom", fFirstDate)
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateTo", sSecondDate)
               sqlDataAdapter sql_adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
               sql_adapter.Fill(dt);
              return dt;
             catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
             {
                string msg = "Error"
                msg += ex.Message;
                throw new Exception(msg);
             }
             finally
             {
                con.Close();
             }
      }
   }
```

And at Button Click event call this function and Store its value into `Session` e.g.

```
     protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {       Session.Add("MyGridData",BindDataGrid1(TextFirstDate.Text,TextSecondDate.Text));
          Response.Redirect("Webform2.aspx");
     }
```

And Now put your grid into your Webform2.aspx and write following code into code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       DataTable dt= (DataTable)Session["MyGridData"];
       if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        { 
             GridView1.DataSource = dt;
             GridView1.DataBind();
       }
    }
```

Comment: I need to return 2 datagrids, is it correct to initiate 2 sql statements and commands?

Comment: Yes. you  can  create a StoredProcedure who return two Tables of result and store this into DataSet and reurnt this DataSet fromm your function and Add this DataSet into Session. On the second Page get data from Session e.g.

 DataSet ds= (DataSet)Session["MyGridData"];
       if (ds.Table[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        { 
             GridView1.DataSource = ds.Table[0].;
             GridView1.DataBind();
       }
 if (ds.Table[1].Rows.Count > 0)
        { 
             GridView2.DataSource = ds.Table[1];
             GridView2.DataBind();
       }

Comment: It is better if you use Storedprocedure. If you dont want to use stored procedure then  initiate 2 sql statements and commands and stored return table in DataTable and Add all this tbales into DataSet. and do rest.

Comment: actually, I don't understand, why return a datatable if my code path is initiating 2 strings?

Comment: Thank you. The DataSet was not really working correctly. The code was correct, but nothing would display. Instead I did another BindGrid() and was able to then initiate another session onto the new page and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I would just create another page with your DataGrid on it and pass the date parameters as querystrings to it on the button click.

Like this:

Page with Button and datepicker:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect(string.Format("MyDataGridPage.aspx?firstDate={0}&secondDate={1}", TextFirstDate.Text, TextSecondDate.Text));
}
```

DataGrid Page:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            var firstDate = Request.QueryString["firstDate"] ?? DateTime.Now;
            var secondDate = Request.QueryString["secondDate"] ?? DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

            BindDataGrid1(firstDate, secondDate);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use cross page post.
In the button  put postback url like this

in the posted page you can get values of date input like this in the pageload event
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         TextBox txtstartdate;
         TextBox txtEnddate;

```
     //getting controls from previous page
     txtstartdate= (TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("textboxID1");
     txtEnddate= (TextBox)PreviousPage.FindControl("textboxID2");
     BindDataGrid1(txtstartdate.Text , txtEnddate.Text);


   }
```